# Warnings from filetype, filesize, and filetime

Tags: php, html

To be quick, I am building a file browser for an application I am using. I am getting the following error when I request the filetype, filesize and filetime. I get the following errors:

Filetype:

```
Warning: filetype() [function.filetype]: Lstat failed
```

filesize:

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed
```

filetime: Shows me that the files were modified 01/01/1970 at 03:00:00 AM. I was surely not editing those files then!

Regardless, here's my code. I apologize for the spaghetti of echos! Please help!

```
<table class="tftable">
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Last Modified</th><th>Size</th></tr>

<?php
if($_GET['folder'] == "")
{
$baseusrdir = "/userfiles/john";
}
else
{
$baseusrdir = "/userfiles/john/".$_GET['folder'];
}

$listdir = scandir(".".$baseusrdir);
$lstdr = $_GET['folder'];

foreach($listdir as $lstdr)
{   
    if($lstdr != "." && $lstdr !="..")
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='files.php?folder=".$_GET['folder']."/$lstdr'>".$lstdr."</a></td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $baseusrdir."/".$lstdr;
    echo filetype($baseusrdir."/".$lstdr);
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo date ("d/m/Y h:i:s A.", filemtime($entry));
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo round((filesize($lstdr)/1000), 2);
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
$arr = explode('/' , $_GET['folder']);
for($i=0;$i<(count($arr)-1);$i++){
    if(!empty($arr[$i])){
        $link.="/".$arr[$i];
    }

}
echo "</br><a href='files.php?folder=$link'>back</a>";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: [As `Lstat` and `stat` are very basic Unix/Linux commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(Unix)) this maybe is an issue related to a funny server setup or a file permission issue. Please check if you can access the files from outside PHP and which owner and permissions are set to them.

Comment: You're asking for hurting if you don't escape that GET data.

Comment: @feeela: I tried this on another computer running Windows and I got the same warning.

Comment: @Daedalus: Thanks for the comment. Will def. do! :)

Answer (score 3):

Abhi Jain - quote:

> The most common cause of filetype() raising this warning and not
>   showing a filetype() in the output (it actually returns NULL) is, if
>   you happened to pass just the 'Dir or File Name' and not the complete
>   "Absolute or Relative Path" to that 'file or Dir'. It may still read
>   that file and return its filetype as "file" but for Dir's it shows
>   warning and outputs NULL. eg: $pathToFile = '/var/www'; $file =
>   'test.php'; $dir = 'somedir';

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php - see coments

Comment: Why are you linking to the french site?  The english one has the same comments.

Comment: lol, havent noticed. went directly to comment section :) fixed

Comment: @LorDex I have tried adding the solution proposed. As you can see, I have `echo filetype($baseusrdir."/".$lstdr);`. This isn't working for either files or folders. I have tried it without $baseusrdir and with.

Comment: @user105084 Is `/userfiles` the root directory of your system, or your site?

Comment: @Daedalus It's a folder that is within the site. It is not the root. Oddly enough this has worked using other code else where. I can't seem to get it to go with this block of code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the file type, I use this function:

```
function getFileType($file){
    $path_chunks = explode("/", $file);
    $thefile = $path_chunks[count($path_chunks) - 1];
    $dotpos = strrpos($thefile, ".");
    return strtolower(substr($thefile, $dotpos + 1));
}
```